# Fixed Period Tracking Calculations In Kotlin Android Application

Tags: android, kotlin

The period tracker is a component in my system am building , the issue am facing is the calculations , to be specific the logic just doesn't add up in my view .

### Strucuture

- Current or Next Period date
- Prevous Period date
- Next Period date
- Current or Next Fertility Phase

here is the data class that the initial start calabration starts on , the user inputs this information

````
@Entity(tableName = "MENSTRUAL_CYCLES")
data class GeneralMenstrualCycle(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    var previous_start_date: String? = null,
    val previous_end_date: String? = null,
    val cycle_length: String?= null,
    val longest_cycle: String? = null,
    val notes: String? = null
) {
    constructor() : this(0,"", "", "", "", "")
} ```

the issue is getting the correct calculation , for the current period days and ovulation cycler, the chances of getting pregnant and the probable end date of the period , and next start date. but as well as updateing the values as previous start date and previous end date
````

lifecycleScope.launch {
val userMenstrualCycles = Constructor.getMenstrualCyclesFromLocalDatabase(appDatabase)
userMenstrualCycles?.let { cycleValues ->
val currentDateMillis = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
val previousEndDateMillis = cycleValues.previous_end_date?.let { endDateStr ->
val endDate = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US).parse(endDateStr)
endDate?.time ?: 0
} ?: currentDateMillis

```
            val averageCycleLengthMillis = cycleValues.cycle_length!!.toInt() * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            val nextPeriodStartDateMillis = previousEndDateMillis + averageCycleLengthMillis
            val currentDayMillis = currentDateMillis - nextPeriodStartDateMillis
            val currentDay = (currentDayMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toInt()

            if (currentDay == 0) {
                showCycleStartPopup(context, auth, db)
                val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US)
                cycleValues.previous_start_date = dateFormat.format(currentDateMillis)
                updateFirebaseDatabase(
                    "previous_start_date",
                    dateFormat.format(nextPeriodStartDateMillis).toString(),
                    auth,
                    db
                )
            }

            val nextFertileStartDateMillis = nextPeriodStartDateMillis + (averageCycleLengthMillis * 0.4).toLong()
            val safeLowFertilityStartMillis = nextFertileStartDateMillis - (averageCycleLengthMillis * 0.2).toLong()
            val safeHighFertilityEndMillis = nextFertileStartDateMillis + (averageCycleLengthMillis * 0.2).toLong()

            val safetyLevel = when {
                currentDateMillis < safeLowFertilityStartMillis -> "Low"
                currentDateMillis <= safeHighFertilityEndMillis -> "Medium"
                else -> "High"
            }

            val textColor = when {
                currentDay in 1 until 5 -> Color.RED
                (currentDay >= 5) && (currentDay <= cycleValues.cycle_length.toInt()) -> Color.YELLOW
                else -> Color.LTGRAY
            }

            avarageCycleView.text = cycleValues.cycle_length.toString()
            val nextPeriodStartDateFormatted = SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMM", Locale.US).format(nextPeriodStartDateMillis)
            nextPeriodStartDate.text = nextPeriodStartDateFormatted
            nextPeriodIn.text = "$currentDay Days"
            nextFertilePhase.text = SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMM", Locale.US).format(nextFertileStartDateMillis)
            chancesOfPregnancy.text = safetyLevel
            cycleVariation.text = "${(cycleValues.longest_cycle!!.toInt() - cycleValues.cycle_length.toInt())} days"
            periodLengthView.text = "${cycleValues.cycle_length} days"
            longestCycleView.text = "${cycleValues.longest_cycle} days"

            avarageCycleView.setTextColor(textColor)
            nextPeriodStartDate.setTextColor(textColor)
            nextPeriodIn.setTextColor(textColor)
            nextFertilePhase.setTextColor(textColor)
            chancesOfPregnancy.setTextColor(textColor)
            cycleVariation.setTextColor(textColor)
            periodLengthView.setTextColor(textColor)
            longestCycleView.setTextColor(textColor)
        }
    }
```

```
My mind is failing to function here have tried doing extensive research but can't find a diffinitive logic to track periods and ovulation in my system. I don't think the calculations are even romotely correct. 

[Here is the current working theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB4u9.png)
this has taken the input of last period start date as Sep 09, 2023 which based on the persons date input it predicted correctly. but the persons period days where 5 not 3 which makes the current on going calculations very questionable. either am just confused or something isn't current in the code and not end date yet... calculated since the previous value for start date was updated and the end date hasn't been update its still at Aug 17, 2023
```